# How to WriteValue for all bindings

Tags: c#, vb.net, data-binding

I am planning to use .NET data binding for a small project, which is mostly a configuration editor. So a collection of settings is bound to a form, loaded from app.config at the start, and saved back at any time (with prompt). No formatting, no validation, no database - very simple setup. I don't trust .NET to perform random callbacks, so plan to use manual update with `Binding.WriteValue`, so user can either apply or reject any changes made.

**Is there any native .NET object that I can use to trigger `WriteValues` for all bindings?** I've looked at `BindingContext` and `BindingManagerBase`, but did not find a good working example on how to use them.

I know there is `BindingSource.ResetBindings`, which is a logical equivalent to `ReadValue` (there is no `ReadValue` member), so looking for something like this to write the values back.

I would like to avoid going through all controls hierarchy and enumerating through each of their bindings individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still need an answer to this, but here it is.

Lambda (Short):

```
Controls.Cast<Control>().ForEach(control=>control.DataBindings.Cast<Binding>().ForEach(binding=>binding.WriteValue()));
```

Classic (Long):

```
foreach (var control in Controls.Cast<Control>())
{
     foreach (var binding in control.DataBindings.Cast<Binding>())
     {
         binding.WriteValue();
     }
}
```

I don't know how many controls you have on your Form, but that can not be with good performance. Also if you have nested controls, you need to invoke it recursive.

Better assign the values to the Istance of the Class that you assign to the DataSource. Don't write it to the controls property, better write it in the data store. then you can use the binding and invoke ResetBindings  to refresh the values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up with something like that eventually. Hard to remember exactly, because the need was more than a year ago. And I also changed job since then. :) Anyway, +1 and accepting.